# Wrapper error while starting sonarqube 6.7.5

Tags: sonarqube

I'm seeing below error while starting SonarQube 6.7.5

```
Y:\sonarqube-6.7.5\bin\windows-x86-64>StartSonar.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapperp | server socket creation failed. (An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726))
wrapperp | server socket creation failed. (An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726))
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
wrapperp | server socket creation failed. (An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726))
wrapperp | server socket creation failed. (An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726))
wrapperp | server socket creation failed. (An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726))
wrapperp | server socket creation failed. (An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726))
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 0.
jvm 1    | java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
jvm 1    | Exiting JVM...
wrapperp | server socket creation failed. (An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726))
wrapperp | server socket creation failed. (An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726))
```

My java verison is :

```
C:\Users\Shiv.Dewangan>java -version
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)
```

I've also tried to change

```
wrapper.java.command=java 
to
wrapper.java.command=D:/apps/Java/jre1.8.0_112_x64/bin/java
```

in wrapper.conf but no help. Any clue please ?

Adding the debug log :

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Using tick timer.
server socket creation failed. (An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726))
server socket creation failed. (An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726))
Launching a JVM...
command: "D:\apps\Java\jre1.8.0_112_x64\bin\java" -Dsonar.wrapped=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms8m -Xmx32m -Djava.library.path="./lib" -classpath "../../lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar;../../lib/common/commons-codec-1.8.jar;../../lib/common/commons-io-2.4.jar;../../lib/common/commons-lang-2.6.jar;../../lib/common/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;../../lib/common/elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar;../../lib/common/elasticsearch-rest-client-5.6.3.jar;../../lib/common/guava-18.0.jar;../../lib/common/hazelcast-3.8.6.jar;../../lib/common/hazelcast-client-3.8.6.jar;../../lib/common/HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar;../../lib/common/hppc-0.7.1.jar;../../lib/common/httpasyncclient-4.1.2.jar;../../lib/common/httpclient-4.5.2.jar;../../lib/common/httpcore-4.4.5.jar;../../lib/common/httpcore-nio-4.4.5.jar;../../lib/common/jackson-core-2.9.5.jar;../../lib/common/jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.8.6.jar;../../lib/common/jackson-dataformat-smile-2.8.6.jar;../../lib/common/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.8.6.jar;../../lib/common/jna-4.4.0-1.jar;../../lib/common/joda-time-2.9.5.jar;../../lib/common/jopt-simple-5.0.2.jar;../../lib/common/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;../../lib/common/log4j-api-2.8.2.jar;../../lib/common/log4j-core-2.8.2.jar;../../lib/common/log4j-to-slf4j-2.8.2.jar;../../lib/common/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;../../lib/common/logback-core-1.2.3.jar;../../lib/common/lucene-analyzers-common-6.6.1.jar;../../lib/common/lucene-backward-codecs-6.6.1.jar;../../lib/common/lucene-core-6.6.1.jar;../../lib/common/lucene-grouping-6.6.1.jar;../../lib/common/lucene-highlighter-6.6.1.jar;../../lib/common/lucene-join-6.6.1.jar;../../lib/common/lucene-memory-6.6.1.jar;../../lib/common/lucene-misc-6.6.1.jar;../../lib/common/lucene-queries-6.6.1.jar;../../lib/common/lucene-queryparser-6.6.1.jar;../../lib/common/lucene-sandbox-6.6.1.jar;../../lib/common/lucene-spatial-6.6.1.jar;../../lib/common/lucene-spatial-extras-6.6.1.jar;../../lib/common/lucene-spatial3d-6.6.1.jar;../../lib/common/lucene-suggest-6.6.1.jar;../../lib/common/netty-buffer-4.1.13.Final.jar;../../lib/common/netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar;../../lib/common/netty-codec-http-4.1.13.Final.jar;../../lib/common/netty-common-4.1.13.Final.jar;../../lib/common/netty-handler-4.1.13.Final.jar;../../lib/common/netty-resolver-4.1.13.Final.jar;../../lib/common/netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar;../../lib/common/parent-join-client-5.6.3.jar;../../lib/common/percolator-client-5.6.3.jar;../../lib/common/reindex-client-5.6.3.jar;../../lib/common/securesm-1.1.jar;../../lib/common/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;../../lib/common/snakeyaml-1.15.jar;../../lib/common/sonar-main-6.7.5.jar;../../lib/common/sonar-process-6.7.5.jar;../../lib/common/t-digest-3.0.jar;../../lib/common/transport-5.6.3.jar;../../lib/common/transport-netty4-client-5.6.3.jar;../../lib/sonar-application-6.7.5.jar" -Dwrapper.key="3vFWJRiR3ITHrjH8" -Dwrapper.port=0 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.debug="TRUE" -Dwrapper.pid=6268 -Dwrapper.version="3.2.3" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp org.sonar.application.App
JVM started (PID=6404)
server socket creation failed. (An invalid argument was supplied. 
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Wrapper Manager: JVM #1
Running a 64-bit JVM.
Wrapper Manager: Registering shutdown hook
Wrapper Manager: Using wrapper
Load native library.  One or more attempts may fail if platform specific libraries do not exist.
Loading native library failed: wrapper-windows-x86-64.dll  Cause: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no wrapper-windows-x86-64 in java.library.path
Loaded native library: wrapper.dll
Calling native initialization method.
Initializing WrapperManager native library.
Java Executable: D:\apps\Java\jre1.8.0_112_x64\bin\java.exe
Windows version: 6.1.7601
Java Version   : 1.8.0_112-b15 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
Java VM Vendor : Oracle Corporation

Control event monitor thread started.
Startup runner thread started.
WrapperManager.start(org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp@31cefde0, args[]) called by thread: main
Communications runner thread started.
Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection
Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 0.
java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
Exiting JVM...
WrapperManager.stopImmediate(1) called by thread: Wrapper-Connection
server socket creation failed. (An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726))
server socket creation failed. (An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726))
server socket creation failed. (An invalid argument was supplied. (0x2726))
CTRL-C trapped.  Shutting down.
```

I did little google and added -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true into wrapper.conf but it's same error.

```
jvm 1    | Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 0.
jvm 1    | java.net.ConnectException: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine
jvm 1    | Exiting JVM...
```

Comment: Try to add the full path to the /bin folder where java executable is located

Comment: Hi Jckhan, Thanks, JVM can be started fine, it's just that wrapper manager is not start/initialize, so JVM is failed to connect to wrapper. I've added the details debug log where it says **Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 0**  and **Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on remote machine**

Comment: Could you provide the configuration of your <install_directory>/conf/sonar.properties file ?

Comment: Hi @jckhan sonar.properties file is as same as it comes with download sonarqube-6.7.5 package. The only line I change is to enable to DEBUG logging mode. **sonar.log.level=DEBUG**. Not much information I see on Wrapper error. I tried with SonarQube 7.3 but same error :-(

Comment: wrapper-windows-x86-64 , maybe there is a chance you are running a sonarqube 64 bits on a 32 bits OS ?